# How to use today's date if DateTime is null?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm quite new to programming. I use ASP.NET Core 3.0 with MVC. I want to get that if user enters no date then the date is set to today

I've tried making an if statement in the Model's constructor and setting the todays time as a default value

```
public class Post
{
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public Post()
    {
        if (ReleaseDate == null)
        {
            ReleaseDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Create method in controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Title,Author,ReleaseDate,ExpirationDate,Content")] Post post)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(post);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(post);
        }
```

The problem is that it doesnt work, the date is null anyway

Comment: i tried the code and it worked. do you get any message?

Comment: What is your code where you are setting the ReleaseDate property equal to the users input?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.
That portion of your code looks good. How is the call being made?

Comment: Do you need to consider the timezone you are in when you decide what "today's time" means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using an instance of `Post` as a parameter in `HttpPost` action method? Perhaps the model binder is creating an instance of the object with the default value you specified, but then assigning `null`.  Consider testing for null in the action method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyMethod(Post post)
{
    if (post.ReleaseDate == null)
    {
        post.ReleaseDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    // other stuff
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that worked, I didn't think about it, thank you very much!